# Axios and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

Can anyone help me. So im trying to "link" my database with my react app with axios but when i post a username it says : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. And also my post request dont seem to work when im not using nodemon.

Btw im using MongoDB for database.

Heres the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
export default class createuser extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.OnChangeUsername = this.OnChangeUsername.bind(this);
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
this.state = {
username: ""
    }
  }
OnChangeUsername(e){
this.setState({
username: e.target.value
    });
  }
onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
const user = {
username: this.state.username
    }
console.log(user);
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
this.setState({
username:''
    })
  }
```

---

Server/Backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


require('dotenv').config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Server running on port : ${port}`);
});
```

I turned on nodemon and i could post new usernames but when i turn it off i cant post usernames and the data doesnt get sent to MongoDB.

Comment: You need to share more information about your backend. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is most probably caused by the backend api not listening on the port specified (5000 in your case).

Comment: Just posted the backend code

Comment: It seems you're turning off the api when you turned off nodemon. Try running with `node {server.js filepath}`.

Comment: But like that the app doesn't start in the browser. Only the server will connect to mongoDB

Comment: The backend is seperate from the front end. You need to run in in two terminals when not in nodemon. To run the frontend `npm run start` for Dev mode.